# Floating point exception: 8 on ruby sinatra with ibm_db gem

Tags: ruby, db2, sinatra

I am getting

```
Floating point exception: 8
```

with no further description, the program just fails

when I run it as test from rspec, everything is fine, but when I run it as a method from route endpoint, it fails

```rb
post '/test' do
  test_code
end
```

is there any way to catch more meaning full error than that? How to do that?

test code just do regular database connection and inserts data. As I stated, works ok when alone, but not from sinatra.

I am calling endpoint from Postman.

Did you encounter something similar?

If you need more detail, please ask.

Thank you for help.

specs:
ruby 2.3.3, sinatra 2+,  ibm_db 3.0.5 with arel 8.0.0, os x 10.14.6

Comment: You have tagged Db2, but there's no information in your question regarding the SQL or the environment (operating systems, versions, bitness), or *where* the exception is happening (ruby, ibm_db, Db2-client etc).  Do  some debugging or most a minimal complete example.

Comment: it is ibm_db, I wanted to add that as tag but there is no ibm_db tag on stack owerflow. I will and to the question, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: You may be caught in a version-support trap with your ruby version and your ibm_db version. Bitness and Db2-client version, and Db2-server version+platform may be relevant, along with the actual SQL.  If you cannot debug or make an mcve for your question, maybe open an issue on github where the module is maintained:  https://github.com/ibmdb/ruby-ibmdb/issues .